# (excel 2013) Dynamic change of formula depending on number of items in another sheet

Tags: excel, dynamic, formula

i have a specific problem to solve. I dont know how to do it but want to do it without macro or worse without VB script.

I will explain what i have and then what i want to do.
I have (plan to have) many sheets in worksheet. first sheet is some intro sheet, where i have also one column containing name of sheets in every cell. i am using formula "=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256)" so i can change name of sheet and it will change also name of sheet in intro sheet cell.

so for imagination i have column N and there i have sheet1, under that sheet2 and so on...
Each of sheets have the same construction and same formulas on the same place, so i have each sheet for every goods.

And now what i would like to have. I want to add a formula into intro sheet where i would summarize SUM (add) or something like that. It would take every value form each sheet on the same place on each sheet. so the formula would look something like this: "=sheet1!C4 + sheet2!C4 + sheet3!C4 + .... + 'any sheet'!C4" but i dont know how many sheets i will have and the number will sometimes change and i dont want to edit formula because i plan to have more this kind of dynamic formulas.

i will just add another sheet into column N and every formula using this excel type for cycle would take and recount formula using this dynamic array. i hope you understand what i want. my problem is much more complicated but when i describe it more into detials you would loose the point of my interest.

thanks for any suggestions

edit: but if there is only a solution using VBA script, i will have to use it. i dont want to change formula everytime i add another sheet into worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is a 3D formula. You can do something like

```
=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet4!A1)
```

Excel will sum cell A1 in all sheets from Sheet1 to Sheet4 and any sheets that are between these two. You can insert new sheets and they don't have to be named SheetX.

In order to manage the 3D formulas more efficiently, you could use two sheets like bookends before and after the sheets you want to include in the formula: Insert two sheets called "First" and "Last" and ensure that all sheets you want to sum are arranged between these two sheets. Then on your intro sheet use

```
=SUM(First:Last!A1)
```

You can hide the "First" and "Last" sheets and only unhide them when you need to check your sheet arrangements for your formulas.

You can insert new sheets and make sure that they are located between your bookend sheets. Drag sheets in and out between the bookends to include or exclude them from the 3D formula.