# (excel 2013) 3D formula with VLOOKUP function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

some time ago i was asking similar question in here
[3D formula with the same position of cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352610/excel-2013-dynamic-change-of-formula-depending-on-number-of-items-in-another-s/25353705#25353705)
but now i am facing much more difficult problem. I have a sheet named Storage and other sheets called simply shop1, shop2.

In storage i have all of my good which are sold but not in every shop i sell the same and all goods. so in some shop you dont find specific good for example.
And now what i want. In every sheet i store number of sold goods and in storage i would like to have the SUM number of all sold goods. so i would lookup if an item from the storage is sold in each shop and if yes, it would lookup the number and add it to sum.

it is easy if the items from the storage would be always on the same row. for example the sum for all items on the row 2 would be

`=SUM(Shop1:Shop4!C2)`

but there would be plenty white and waste places because the shop sell only part of goods from storage. so now i would like to use VLOOKUP function into it. i thaught i can use

`=SUM(VLOOKUP(A2;shop1:shop2!A:B;2;FALSE))`

but this formula gives me error message. so how to give 3D formula into VLOOKUP function?

thanks for answer

Edit: I want to add that an item from the storage is not always on the same row on each shop, so for example item1 can be on the third row in shop1 sheet but on the 10th row on the shop2 sheet and in the shop3 sheet you will not even find item1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to Name Manager (*Formulas* tab) and define the following:

*Name:* SheetList

*Refers to:* ={"shop1","shop2","shop3","shop4"}

(Or whatever happen to be the sheet names in question.)

The required formula is then:

=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!A:A");A2;INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!B:B")))

Regards

Comment: this gives me an error and i think it makes some infinite cycle or at least when I enter this formula my excel works very slow

Comment: What type of error? I trust you only included the relevant tab names in the Named Range, and not e.g. the tab in which the actual formula resides (assumed to be some sort of master sheet)?

Comment: your formula actually shows some number but after a while (2 seconds) the cell changes state to Value is not available N/A. so i suppose that formula is still working. I can send you my own formula but i have to translate it into czech because i have have czech version of excel

Comment: ok the problem was with the named array of sheets. i looked at defined names and saw that aray didnt consist only of (in my case) three sheets but was infinite {"shop1";"shop2";"shop3";;;;;;;;;;;;} because i selected whole column and not only that three name of sheets. i changed it only to {"shop1";"shop2";"shop3"} manually so it now shows correct number. If you would be so kind and tell me if a can make this named list of sheets more dynamic. when i add another sheet into next row of that column it will automatically change named arrray to {"shop1";"shop2";"shop3";"shop4"}

Comment: you have to give "=OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),1)" into "Refers to:" field