# Generating vLookup-formula with over 250 "parts" with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My questions is: How can I add multiple vLookup-formulas into one cell over VBA?

I know that I can add one vLookUp like this:

```
... = Application.WorksheetFunction.vLookUp("Search","Matrix","Index")
```

My Problem is: I have a workbook with 255 pages and in my "sum-sheet" I need variable formulas that search in those 255 worksheets for the data I need.
So the output of the macro in excel needs to be something like (all of in one cell):

```
=vLoookUp($A2;Sheet1!A1:A1000;2)+SVERWEIS($A2;Sheet2!A1:A1000;2)+ ...(255 times)
```

Is it even possible to do something like that with VBA?

This is the code I used to split the different options into the 255 sheets:

This is the code I wrote so far to split the different variations of stocks:
(Its somewhat working but I'm kind of sure its not very efficient, I'm new to all this Programming Stuff)

```
Sub Sheets()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized

Dim Data As String
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As String


For i = 2 To 255

Sheetname = Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 1).Value
Worksheets.Add.Name = Sheetname
ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

x = 1

For k = 2 To 876
Data = Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, k).Value
y = Cells(1, x).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
BloomB = "=BDH(" & y & ",""TURNOVER"",""8/1/2011"",""4/30/2016"",""Dir=V"",""Dts=S"",""Sort=A"",""Quote=C"",""QtTyp=Y"",""Days=T"",""Per=cd"",""DtFmt=D"",""UseDPDF=Y"")"
Worksheets(Sheetname).Cells(1, x) = Data
Worksheets(Sheetname).Cells(2, x) = BloomB
x = x + 2
Next k

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Next i

ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm aware that the question is vague. But with limited skills in VBA im simply not able to ask any more specific. I'm really hoping there is still someone out there who can maybe help me.

Comment: look into looping through sheets use a variable to store the sum and add each subsequent loop to it.

Comment: The maximum length of a formula is 8192 in Excel 2016 so you may be approaching that limit if your lookups are too long. You may have to break it up into two or three cells. It isn't clear if you want to calculate in VB (as your example shows) or create a formula using VB that is calculated by Excel calculation engine?

Comment: `debug.print application.evaluate("=VLoookUp($A2;Sheet1!A1:A1000;2)+SVERWEIS($A2;Sheet2!A1:A1000;2)+ ...")`

Comment: I want to create a formula that will be calculated by excel calculation engine.

Comment: oops ... no good ... this one has a 255 character limit

Comment: I want to calculate the average total turnover of a stock on every day of the last 5 years (1735 days). They get traded in 255 different markets and there are 875 different stocks.

So I split them up and now got 255 sheets and every sheet has all the dates and every combination with all the different stocks in it.

My goal is now to have a "sum-up" sheet where every single stock has his average turnover for any given date.

I hope this helps to explain my problem a little.

Comment: you could assign formulas to cells (in a hidden sheet, if you want)  `range("a1").Formula = "=VLoookUp($A2;Sheet1!A1:A1000;2)+SVERW‌​EIS($A2;Sheet2!A1:A1‌​000;2)"`

Comment: @Yarza Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45702783/edit) your question when you want to add more information. Comments can get deleted at any time.

Comment: do i understand this correctly?  you have 255 data + 1 sumUp sheets. each sheet has 1735+ rows and 875+ columns

Comment: yes, and all the sheets are filled with bloomberg data. I will post the code I use to generate the different sheets so you maybe have a better impression.

Comment: I'm thankful for all the input I got so far.
I get the impression that my question/goal is kind of stupid/impossible though. If this is the case: please tell me! I'm very new to VBA and excel with big data sheets, so sadly I dont really know whats possible and what is not.

Comment: Is the layout of each and every sheet the same?  I.e. can you just sum the same cell from each sheet?

Comment: yes the layout of all sheets is basically the same. Except: not all stocks (255) have data from all days (1735). Since some days they didnt get traded. And bloomberg doesnt make gaps they just put all the dates in one column without gaps. So that changes. But you can find the same market combination in the same column in every sheet.

Comment: Despite Bloomberg not providing data for each stock for each date, you would be better off if you changed your process so that your sheets **do** have details for each stock for each date.  (i.e. update the code that populates the sheets with the daily Bloomberg data.)  Then it becomes a trivial exercise to do a `=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet255!A5)` type calculation.

Comment: How about a 3D Vlookup similar to [(excel 2013) 3D formula with VLOOKUP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364626/excel-2013-3d-formula-with-vlookup-function).

Since it would be tedious to manually type in all the sheet names (and I also don't know what the character limit might be in a Named formula), just enter the sheet names in some range on your summary sheet, and have the Named Formula refer to that range.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this sounds like a very bad design.  Maybe Access or SQL Server would be better suited for this kind of task.  Also, you know the VLOOKUP function will return the first match, but no subsequent matches, right.  Just want to make you aware of that.  Ok, now try this.

```
Function VLOOKAllSheets(Look_Value As Variant, Tble_Array As Range, _
                          Col_num As Integer, Optional Range_look As Boolean)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Written by OzGrid.com
'Use VLOOKUP to Look across ALL Worksheets and stops _
at the first match found.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim vFound

On Error Resume Next

    For Each wSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wSheet
        Set Tble_Array = .Range(Tble_Array.Address)
            vFound = WorksheetFunction.VLookup _
            (Look_Value, Tble_Array, _
            Col_num, Range_look)
        End With
        If Not IsEmpty(vFound) Then Exit For
    Next wSheet

    Set Tble_Array = Nothing
    VLOOKAllSheets = vFound

End Function
```

The full description of everything is here.

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VlookupAllSheets.htm